# Why do C# HashSets have a Distinct() method

Tags: c#, hashset

Why is there a Distinct() method available on the HashSet when they cannot contain duplicates anyway?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Distinct` method is not on the `HashSet<>`, but the `IEnumerable<>` that is implemented by the `HashSet<>`.

Extension methods cannot be "omitted" from certain types. Once added to a type, all of that type and any derived will get the extension method.

Just to demonstrate, if you extended `object` you'd litter everything if you added the relevant namespace. So don't go adding:

```
namespace System
{
    public static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        public static void Garbage(this object foo)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify `Distinct` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, which `HashSet<T>` happens to implement.

Comment: @jonnyGold Yes I realised, I just edited my answer prior to your comment. Thanks for the clarification anyway.

Comment: To be even more precise, `Distinct` is an extension method, extending `IEnumerable<>` and residing in the static class `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

Comment: Feels a little like a design smell to me

Comment: @atlantis I wouldn't say it is a design smell. Imagine it would just be a normal `interface`, would yield the same problem. But if HashSet defines it's own `Distinct` method, the extension method would be hidden, giving a possibility for optimization